# Creating an XsltListViewWebPart programmatically: Columns & toolbar

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, splimitedwebpartmanager

I add an XsltListViewWebpart to a page in an event receiver like this:

```
public void CreateWebPart(SPList documentsList, SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm)
{
    var documentsWP = new XsltListViewWebPart();
    documentsWP.ListId = documentsList.ID
    wpm.AddWebPart(documentsWP, "Left", 0);
}
```

This works fine, but I want to change it around a bit. I want to edit the columns that are displayed, and I want to remove the little toolbar at the bottom that allows you to add items. My first attempt was this:

```
public void CreateWebPart(SPList documentsList, SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm)
{
    var documentsWP = new XsltListViewWebPart();
    documentsWP.ListId = documentsList.ID;
    documentsWP.Toolbar = "None"; //this does nothing?
    wpm.AddWebPart(documentsWP, "Left", 0);
}
```

But that did nothing. After that I tried the following:

```
public void CreateWebPart(SPList documentsList, SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm)
{
    var documentsWP= new XsltListViewWebPart();
    documentsWP.ListId = documentsList.ID;
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    xml.Append("<View MobileView='TRUE' Type='HTML'>");
    xml.Append("<Query></Query>");
    xml.Append("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='DocIcon'/><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/></ViewFields>");
    xml.Append("<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>30</RowLimit>");
    xml.Append("<Aggregations Value='Off'/>");
    xml.Append("<Toolbar Type='None'/></View>");
    documentsWP.XmlDefinition = xml.ToString();
    documentsWP.AllowEdit = false;            
    wpm.AddWebPart(documentsWP, "Left", 0);
}
```

But still the toolbar is shown, and still other fields are shown (the Modifier field). How can I programmatically set the displayed columns? How can I hide the toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own view and decide which fields to show in the view.
The method below creates a StringCollection which can be passed to the method while creating view List.Views.Add()

```
    private StringCollection CreateViewColumns()
    {
        StringCollection viewFieldsCollection = new StringCollection();
        string tasksColumns = "ID;Title";
        string[] columns = tasksColumns.Split(';');
        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            viewFieldsCollection.Add(column);
        }
        return viewFieldsCollection;
    }
```

Also, you can use reflection to set the Toolbar to None

```
   MethodInfo ensureViewMethod = lvwp.GetType().GetMethod("EnsureView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object[] ensureViewParams = { };
        ensureViewMethod.Invoke(lvwp, ensureViewParams);
        FieldInfo viewFieldInfo = lvwp.GetType().GetField("view", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        SPView spView = viewFieldInfo.GetValue(lvwp) as SPView;
        Type[] toolbarMethodParamTypes = { Type.GetType("System.String") };
        MethodInfo setToolbarTypeMethod = spView.GetType().GetMethod("SetToolbarType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, toolbarMethodParamTypes, null);
        object[] setToolbarParam = { "None" };
        setToolbarTypeMethod.Invoke(spView, setToolbarParam);
```

For full example, please look into here http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2012/08/programatically-add-xsltlist-view.html

Comment: Just tried the view method and that works perfectly. Also +1 for the link :)

Comment: This seems to be SP2010 specific and does not work for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: @ peter, you are right. It doesn't work in SP2013

Answer (score 4):

I have created this in an application page, which is working fine. Please refer tto the code below that also has your part of code.

```
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString()))
      {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[MyList];
                XsltListViewWebPart XsltListViewWebPart1 = new XsltListViewWebPart();
                XsltListViewWebPart1.ListUrl = @"/Lists/MyList";
                XsltListViewWebPart1.ListId = list.ID;
                SPView lstview = list.DefaultView;
                XsltListViewWebPart1.Toolbar = "";
                // XsltListViewWebPart1.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToString();
                StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
                xml.Append("<View Name='{" + list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToString() + "}' MobileView='TRUE' Type='HTML'  Hidden='TRUE' DisplayName='' Url='" + Request.Url.ToString() + "' Level='1' BaseViewID='1' ContentTypeID='0x' ImageUrl='/_layouts/images/generic.png'>");
                xml.Append("<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'/></OrderBy></Query>");
                xml.Append("<ViewFields> <FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><FieldRef Name='IsActive'/></ViewFields>");
                xml.Append("<RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>30</RowLimit>");
                xml.Append("<Aggregations Value='Off'/>");
                xml.Append("<Toolbar Type='Freeform'/></View>");
                //  documentsWP.XmlDefinition = xml.ToString();
                XsltListViewWebPart1.XmlDefinition = xml.ToString();//lstview.GetViewXml();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(XsltListViewWebPart1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to create XsltListViewWebPart (XLV)

In order to create XLV for a custom view, [XmlDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xmldefinition.aspx) and  [ViewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.viewguid.aspx) properties should be specified:

```
private static WebPart CreateListViewWebPart(SPWeb web,string webPartTitle, string listUrl,string viewName)
{
      var list = web.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, listUrl));
      var view = list.Views[viewName];
      var listView = new XsltListViewWebPart();
      listView.Title = webPartTitle;
      listView.ListUrl = listUrl;
      listView.ListId = list.ID;
      listView.ViewGuid = view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
      listView.XmlDefinition = view.GetViewXml();
      listView.TitleUrl = view.ServerRelativeUrl;
      return listView; 
}
```