# ListView Web Part Associated with List

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-server

Programmatically - How do I get to the listview web part associated with a list or library. I want to customize it and add it to a web page page in SharePoint 2013. I don't see it in the web part gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically, you don't go and get the web part associated with a list. You add a XsltListViewWebPart to a page, and set its associated list to your list's ID.

For example (from [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51599/creating-an-xsltlistviewwebpart-programmatically-columns-toolbar) answer on this site) :

```
var documentsWP = new XsltListViewWebPart();
documentsWP.ListId = documentsList.ID
wpm.AddWebPart(documentsWP, "Left", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the view pages reside below the list. So the URL format will be like

```
http://webapp/site/lists/listname/allitems.aspx
```

You can get list of views using [SPList.Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.views.aspx) property. To get the view URL you can use [Url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.url.aspx) property.

Once you have the URL you can open the file as a `SPFile` object. Then you can use `SPLimitedWebPartManager` to get the webparts on that page.

Comment: I meant listview web part, not page. It was a typo.

Comment: @KyleJohnson I have updated my answer.